# Jupyter notebook parallel tasks with concurrent.futures

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, concurrent.futures

I am trying to do parallel tasks in a Jupyter notebook. Hoping someone can tell me what should I do or what should I learn.

In my Jupyter notebook, I would loop through an argument from 1 to 10 which passed to another py script. What I want is to let my computer do each argument with one single task. I believe, with that, I would expedite the efficiency.

Here is what I have in my Jupyter notebook:

```
import os
from time import time
start_1 = time()
# parameters
file = 'Tool_1.py' # the single py script which I would run in a single loop
file_1 = 'my_data.csv'
skiprows = 4
stop_loss_point_init = -50
stop_gain_point = 800
move_step = 100
move_far = 50 
# loop body
for window in range(1, 11): # I would loop window from 1 to 10
    start_2 = time()
    cmd = 'python %s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d' % (file,file_1,skiprows,window,stop_loss_point_init,stop_gain_point,move_step,move_far)
    print('Running '+str(cmd))
    os.system(cmd)
    output_file = 'output_file.csv'
    end_2 = time()
    print(output_file)
    print("Exported in {:.2f} minutes.".format((end_2 - start_2)/60))

end_1 = time()
print("Completed in {:.2f} minutes.".format((end_1 - start_1)/60))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution is [ipyparallel](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#getting-started).
You can create engines inside **Jupyter-Notebook** to do the parallel computing.

os.system() always waits untill the child process finishes, so you shouldn't use it for parallel computing. A better solution would be to define a method and use ipyparalles `map()` method as shown in this [example](http://ipyparallel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demos.html).

Comment: My objective is to compute the whole task in a more efficient way. It sounds `ipyparallel` would help me. Do you know anything about `concurrent.futures` and `multiprocessing`? Would they work in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: concurrent.futures will work in Jupyter Notebook as well. I would suggest to use its `ProcessPoolExecuter` to start a new process for all of your calculations, so you can use all of your computer's cores. Here is a nice example how to use this [concurrent.future](http://masnun.com/2016/03/29/python-a-quick-introduction-to-the-concurrent-futures-module.html)